# What type of data can be stored in cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning ASP.net using C# and I would like to know if we can store data other than strings, in cookies, like date/time or decimal or double.

Answer (score 13):

Data of any type you can serialize into a `string` and deserialize back into that type can be stored in a cookie. For instance: `Object`, `DateTime`, `Int`, `Decimal`, etc.

---

It entirely depends on your coding logic; string can be converted back to anything almost,

- Object
- Int
- Decimal
- DateTime
- Reference to any temporary table / value u may keep for guest users

---

> Is possible to get the object from cookie?

No, not directly as you are trying to. Don't think in terms of ASP.NET. Think in terms of what an [HTTP cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is in reality. It is an HTTP header. HTTP headers are only plain string values. The notion of object doesn't exist in the HTTP protocol.

So you will need to serialize the .NET object that you have into a string and then deserialize it back.

There are different serializers in .NET that you could use. For example use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) and then [Base64 encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) the resulting byte array to store into the cookie.

The deserialization is the inverse process - you read the value from the cookie (which is always a string), then you [Base64 decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) it into a byte array which you deserialize back to the original object using the `BinaryFormatter`.

Bear in mind though that the size of the cookies is limited and would vary between the different browsers. So don't expect to put large objects into cookies. The value will be stripped and you would get corrupt data. I wouldn't use them if the total serialized value of the object is larger than 2k characters.

Let's exemplify the process described earlier:

```
public class cookieTest
{
    testC test;
    public cookieTest()
    {
        test = new testC();
    }
    public testC GetTestC
    {
        get
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["test"];
            return Deserialize<testC>(cookie.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
            cookie["first"] = Serialize(value);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }

    private static string Serialize<T>(T instance)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string value)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(value)))
        {
            var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Credit & Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996305/c-sharp-cookie-cannot-convert-type-string-to-x)

Comment: The answer to [c# cookie cannot convert type 'string' to 'x'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996305/c-sharp-cookie-cannot-convert-type-string-to-x) has a good explanation of this along with a code sample showing one way to serialize an object so it can be passed into a cookie and deserializing a cookie’s value back into an object.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use your process once I figure out the serialize method.

Answer (score 3):

The data is always stored as type `String`. However, since you are the one who stored the data you should know the data type. So, when reading back the data you can use the appropriate conversion functions to get whatever datatype you need.